# How can you send data (via cellular) from an Arduino to a server?

Tags: arduino, communication

I'm pretty new to IoT so forgive the basic questions, but I need to send data from an Arduino that is constantly collecting sensor data to a home server.

I wanted to know where to start with this problem, and how the Arduino would communicate with a server. I want to send the data via cellular since the wifi in the area is pretty unpredictable. I'm also not sure what form the data will take on my server since it's just a storage database.

Answer (score 3):

There is Arduino shields with a GSM/LTE modem. Use a search engine and searh for "arduino gsm lte".

That will create a TCP/IP connection (Internet) that you can use to communicate with other IP devices.

How to communicate between the IP addresses is another topic involving public IP, Firewalls, Public services and protocols.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started [Arduino-Using-AWS-IoT-Serivce](https://www.instructables.com/Arduino-Using-AWS-IoT-Serivce/). There are many other sources of information if you google "AWS IoT arduino".

Regarding what to do with your data, it will be helpful to know what type of data this is, to give you more advice. It would be very simple to add an IoT rule to just accumulate the data as records in an S3 data store, for example [this step by step guide](https://www.cloudthat.com/resources/blog/step-by-step-guide-to-store-aws-iot-data-into-s3-bucket) (that web page is a bit slow to load!), or [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54441780/how-to-push-data-from-aws-iot-mqtt-broker-to-a-random-file-in-s3-bucket).

The example I gave above is AWS based. You can find similar examples for Azure and Google, as well as others such as thingsboard.io too.